# Why google calculator gives $\sin 90^\circ = 0.8939966636$

Tags: calculator

Why Google calculator shows $\sin 90^\circ = 0.8939966636$, when we all know that $\sin 90^\circ = 1$ ?

---

[image: Google Search]

Comment: You can enter "sin 90 deg" into google if you really want degrees.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792365/why-is-cos-90-0-4-in-webgl

Answer (score 10):

`NOTE`: `DEG` stands for degrees and `RAD` for `radians`

Now we need to know two things here, that are :

#### 1. **`Sin ( 90 DEG ) = 1`**

[image: degree]

#### 2. **`Sin ( 90 RAD ) = 0.8939966636`**

[image: radian]

So, When we do a google search for `Sin 90` without passing the measure `it's by-default radians`.

Now you know there is nothing wrong with Google Search.

***Comment to OP by Sil*** - Use `sin 90 deg` into google if you really want degrees.